# php validating output with htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I set a php cookie

```
setcookie('pr','gulfstream',time()...etc...)
```

My validation page has arrays and statements as below.

```
$planes = array('gulfstream','Piper','Citation');

$abc = isset($_COOKIE['pr']) && in_array($_COOKIE['pr'],$planes) ? $_COOKIE['pr']:0;
```

My visitor pages use:

```
echo $abc;
```

Question: is the above safe to output to the page or should I further validate the statement with:

```
$abc = isset($_COOKIE['pr']) && in_array($_COOKIE['pr'],$planes) ? htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['pr']):0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to exploit this code **in this example**.

Anyway I think you have to be aware that it's is to make it exploitable by possibility of type juggling (usually cast to integer `0`).
That's why I suggest you to use strict mode of `in_array` like

```
in_array($_COOKIE['pr'],$planes, true); //third parameter enforces type checking
```

Comment: Right, that's good advice. I'll set that. Are you also saying I don't need htmlspecialchars() in the statement?

Comment: You don't need it since when it is actually a string-to-string comparison, you know what values will be accepted.

Comment: Thanks dragoste, that's a wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you've validated the cookie, it's still meant to contain text, and not HTML code. You should always use htmlspecialchars before outputting text in an HTML document.

Comment: #JW Ok, wait, so you are saying I should go ahead and put that in the location I indicated in the original post?

Comment: I would keep variables un-encoded, and just encode them when you output them in your HTML. That way you can do other things with the variables, like check their length, without the encoding affecting the results.

Comment: Understood, but there are just too many of them in too many pages, I need to do this at this central point on the validation page. That being the case, in my original post, is the location of the htmlspecialchars() correct, in your estimation?